# How to solve $\left| \dfrac{dy}{dx}\right|+|y|=0$, $y(0)=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

How can I solve the differential equation $\left| \dfrac{dy}{dx}\right|+|y|=0$, $y(0)=1$?.
 Is it possible to solve
$|x|=\begin{cases}
x, & x\geq 0\\
-x, & x<0
\end{cases}$.

Comment: There is no solution because the only function satisfying the ODE is $y=0$.

Comment: @amsmath How would I know that there is no solution?

Comment: Consider two real numbers $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $|a|+|b|=0$. You should directly see that the only solution is $a=b=0$. Same with your ODE. But that contradicts $y(0)=1$.

Comment: @amsmath : This expression is no ODE. An ODE defines a vector field, possibly in a non-unique way, on an open subset of the $(x,y)$-time-state space. This equation only defines a derivative on the line $y=0$.

Comment: @LutzL By Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) this is an implicit ODE with $F(x,y,y') = |y'| + |y|$.

Comment: Wikipedia is not really an authority, in general it is right, but fringe cases may not be addressed at all or are classified depending on the taste of the dominant author (which may be true in the general literature too). All theory assumes at least that the hypersurface $\{0=F(x,y,v)\}$ projects down surjectively onto the domain in the $(x,y)$ plane. Usually it is assumed that there is a local solution for $v=f(x,y)$ so that locally the implicit ODE can be converted to explicit form.

Answer (score 4):

Come on, you have the sum of two positive functions which is equal to 0...

Comment: *Non-negative, but yeah

Comment: @asdf  People from the analysis side often like to say "positive functions" to mean "nonnegative functions."

Comment: That is actually my French habit where « positif » is equivalent to your nonnegative.

Comment: @Pjonin However, in English "positive" means $>0$ and we all (try to) speak English here.

Comment: Yes I think I am aware. Thanks for your comment of the greatest help.